# PHPMail method not working in ubuntu with LAMPP

Tags: php

I created a contact form and it works correctly with phpmail method, but I'm facing one issue with not sent email. I'm getting one error based on below code using Ubuntu and LAMPP

```
if (isset($_POST['sendmail'])){
     $person_name=$_POST['c_name']; 
     $email=$_POST['c_email'];
     $subject=$_POST['c_subject'];
     $message=$_POST['c_message'];

    $toEmail = "ourgmail@gmail.com";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $person_name . "<". $email .">\r\n";
    if(mail($toEmail,$subject,$message,$mailHeaders)) {  // checking sent or not
       echo "<script>alert('success')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('error')</script>"; //  email not sent and getting error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write which error message you gets?

Comment: PHP `mail()` does not work on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this comment at PHP mail() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121163):

> Often it's helpful to find the exact error message that is triggered
>   by the mail() function. While the function doesn't provide an error
>   directly, you can use error_get_last() when mail() returns false.
>
> ```
> <?php $success = mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message); 
> if (!$success) {
>     $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message']; 
> } ?>
> ```

Also, keep in mind that to mail() work, your system must be properly configured to send emails. Since setting up a mail server is not so simple (there's a lot of anti-spam restrictions), if you want to test it out, you can setup a `SSMTP` service on your system that uses a third party SMTP service like http://mailgun.com to sent it. Check [this question on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server).